# Can you always prove the asymptotic bound of a recurrence of the form aT(n/b) + f(n) using the substitution method?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

To make my question more concrete, here is an example I am stuck on.

I want to prove that $T(n) = 8T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^3$ is asymptotic bound by $n^3\log(n)$ using the substution method. That is $T(n)$ is $\Theta(n^3\log(n))$, so both $O(n^3\log(n))$ and $\Omega(n^3 \log(n))$.

We know $T(n) = \Theta(n^3 \log(n)) \Leftrightarrow \exists c_1, c_2, n_0 > 0: \forall n > n_0 . c_1 n^3 \log(n) \leq T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log(n)$.

Given that I assume the proof should go somewhat as follows:

**To show**: $\exists c_1, c_2, n_0 > 0: \forall n > n_0 . c_1 n^3 \log(n) \leq T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log(n)$

To do this we can use strong induction.

Let $P(n)$ be $c_1 n^3 \log(n) \leq T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log(n)$.

Take $n$ to be an arbitrary natural number.

**Induction hypothesis**: $P(1),P(2),...,P(n-1)$. And notably, $P(\frac{n}{2})$.

It seems fairly straight forward to show the right-hand side of $P(n)$, that is that $\forall n > n_0 . T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log(n)$.

It follows that (taking $\log$ to be in base $2$):

$$
\begin{align*}
  P(\frac{n}{2}) &\Leftrightarrow T(\frac{n}{2}) \leq c_2 (\frac{n}{2})^3\log(\frac{n}{2}) \\
  &\Leftrightarrow 8T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^3 \leq 8c_2 (\frac{n}{2})^3 \log(\frac{n}{2}) + n^3 \\
  & \Leftrightarrow T(n) \leq 8c_2\frac{n^3}{8}(\log(n) - log(2)) + n^3 \\
  & \Leftrightarrow T(n) \leq c_2n^3\log(n) + n^3 - c_2n^3log(2) \\
  & \Leftrightarrow T(n) \leq c_2n^3\log(n) + n^3 - c_2n^3 \leq c_2n^3\log(n) \ \text{ (if $c_2 \geq 1$)}
\end{align*}
$$

So we have $P(n)$.

And as such $\exists c_2, n_0 > 0: \forall n > n_0 . T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log(n)$.

**My problem:**

So we have shown that $T(n) = O(n^3 \log (n))$ but not yet that $T(n) = \Omega(n^3 \log (n))$ which is also required to have $T(n) = \Theta(n^3 \log(n))$.

And that is what I am not sure how to go about showing — the left-hand side of $P(n)$, that is that given $P(\frac{n}{2})$, we have $c_2 n^3 \log(n) \leq T(n)$.

Can someone provide some insight into how to approach this?

Comment: The variable $n$ is not a free variable in "$\exists c_1, c_2, n_0 > 0: \forall n > n_0 . c_1 n^3 \log(n) \leq T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log(n)$". That is, $P(n)$ does not make sense.

Comment: I am confused by the last line of your induction. Specifically I'm not sure how you got $\tfrac{n^3}{\log}(n)$ or what it really means. Is that what you meant to type or is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: I am guessing it is just a typo from when you cancelled out the 8's. Anyway, your upper bound proof is not quite right. You claim $T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log n$, but then you "prove" $T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log n + n^3$. Your claim does not match what you show, thus your induction hypothesis does not hold. You can fix this by setting $c_2 = 1$ however. Also, with a base case of $T(2) = 8$ you can prove precise equality, that $T(n) = n^3 \log_2 n$ by induction, no need to mess with upper or lower bounds.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I have updated the question to address this issue. Please let me know if the way I have written it out now makes mathematical sense and is logically correct.

Comment: @ryan you are right, that is, in fact, a typo. I have updated the question to fix this issue. I have also updated the question to address the problem of not properly proving $T(n) \leq c_2 n^3 \log n + n^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove precise equality for your recurrence. I'm going to assume the base case:

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
  8 & n = 2\\
  8T\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right) + n^3 & n > 2\\
\end{cases}$$

Claim: $T(n) = n^3 \log_2 n$

Base Case ($n = 2$): $T(2) = 8 = 2^3 \log_2 2 = 8$

Inductive Case ($n > 2$):

$$\begin{align*}
T(n) & = 8T\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right) + n^3\\
     & = 8\left(\tfrac{n^3}{8} \log_2 \tfrac{n}{2}\right) + n^3\\
     & = n^3 \log_2 \tfrac{n}{2} + n^3\\
     & = n^3 \log_2 n - n^3 \log_2 2 + n^3\\
     & = n^3 \log_2 n - n^3 + n^3\\
     & = n^3 \log_2 n & \square
\end{align*}$$

Thus $T(n) = n^3 \log_2 n \implies T(n) = O(n^3 \log n)$. No need to mess with lower or upper bounds.

---

However, in general this equality might not be the correct solution. Sometimes you will need to add lower order terms to get the equality or inequality to hold. A general approach to determine the lower order terms is as follows:

If we have:

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
f(b) & n = b\\
aT(n/b) + f(n) & n > b
\end{cases}$$

We first assume $n = b^k$ for some $k$. Next we can turn this into a summation:

$$\begin{align*}
T(n) & = aT(n/b) + f(n)\\
     & = a(aT(n/b^2) + f(n/b)) + f(n)\\
     & = a^2T(n/b^2) + af(n/b) + f(n)\\
     & \vdots\\
     & = \sum_{i = 0}^{\log_b n - 1} a^{i} f\left( \frac{n}{b^i}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Then if you can find a closed form for this sum, we can easily prove equality by induction (e.g. substitution method) with proper constants. Here is your example again:

$$\begin{align*}
T(n) & = 8T\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right) + n^3\\
     & = \sum_{i = 0}^{\log_2 n - 1} 8^{i} \left( \frac{n}{2^i}\right)^3\\
     & = \sum_{i = 0}^{\log_2 n - 1} 8^{i} \frac{n^3}{2^{3i}}\\
     & = \sum_{i = 0}^{\log_2 n - 1} n^3\\
     & = n^3 \log_2 n\\
\end{align*}$$

Now you can go ahead and use this in your substitution method and you should not have any issues.

---

Feel free to try the same method with a trickier example:

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
  12 & n = 3\\
  5T\left(\tfrac{n}{3}\right) + n^2 + n & n > 3\\
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove a recurrence of the form $$aT(n/b) + f(n)$$ if the constraints for master theorem hold. A bad value for f(n) might invalidate that.

Comment: I don't think this quite answers the question. The Master Theorem will work, yes, but I believe they are asking specifically about how general the substitution method is for recurrences of this form.

Comment: Yes, @ryan is correct — that doesn't answer my question. I know you can solve this easily with the master theorem and get that it is $\Theta(n^3\log n)$, that is in fact how I got my guess for the substitution. What I was asking was how one can show that $T(n)=8T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^3$ is asymptomatically lower bounded by $n^3 \log n$ using the substitution method.